# split array into unknown number of parts with sum of each approximately equal to X

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, split

I have pandas Series pdf_like_series with data looks like pdf of symmetric distribution.
I want to find sequential partition with sum of each chunk is near from center value.
pdf_like_series.loc[i:j] ≈ pdf_like_series[0].
[image]

Comment: I need sequential indexes. Like [0], [1:5], [6:20], [20:100]. I think, not enough information in my question. Center chunk length has to be smaller than or equal to side chunk length. And maybe it's possible only with some precision.

Answer (score 0):

I did some recursive solution. But it is impossible to use with big lists! If you know better please tell me!

```
def recursive_partition(
array: List,
min_step: int,
value_compare: float) -> Tuple[List[int], float]:
"""
Partition array to intervals with sum close to value_compare by minimizing max mistake 
between sum of interval and value_compare
Can work only with small arrays len(array) // min_step < 100

:param array: array with mostly bigger values close to 0 index
:param min_step: smallest possible length of new interval
:param value_compare: all sums are compared to this value

:return: List with numbers of elements in each interval from 0 to len(array) and maximum mistake of partition
"""
max_mistake = abs(value_compare - sum(array))
if min_step > len(array)//2:
    return [len(array)], max_mistake
else:
    possible_left = np.arange(min_step, len(array)//2 + 1, min_step)
    best_mistake = max_mistake
    best_partition = [len(array)]
    best_left = len(array)
    for left in possible_left:
        mistake_left = abs(value_compare - sum(array[0:left]))
        if mistake_left < max_mistake:
            partition, mistake_right = recursive_partition(
                array=array[left:], min_step=left, value_compare=value_compare)
            if best_mistake > max(mistake_left, mistake_right):
                best_mistake = max(mistake_left, mistake_right)
                best_partition = partition.copy()
                best_left = left
    if best_mistake < max_mistake:
        return [best_left] + best_partition, best_mistake
    else:
        return [len(array)], max_mistake
```